# Comparar contenido de dos cadenas en c?

Tags: c

Hola soy nuevo(nuevo programando también) y esta es mi primera pregunta, me gustaría saber como comparar dos cadenas. Esto es lo que hice pero resulta que no me compara sino que me tira el segundo mensaje no mas.

```
char pal1[10],pal2[10];

printf("Ingrese una palabra: "); scanf("%s",pal1);
printf("Ingrese otra palabra: "); scanf("%s",pal2);

if (pal1==pal2){
    printf("\nTienen el mismo contenido!! \n%s\n%s",pal1,pal2);
}else{
    printf("\nSon cadenas de distinto contenido!! \n%s\n%s",pal1,pal2);
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Fede_imfeld!, es importante realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y además obtienes tu primera medalla. Además es **muy importante revisar [ask]** que te brinda información para realizar una buena pregunta, esta sea bien recibida en la comunidad y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas, saludos y suerte!

Comment: Nos da gusto te unas a la comunidad, revisa la información que te proporciono, en realidad no es propiamente un "foro" es más que eso,  es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas para programadores y entusiastas del desarrollo y uso de software. Saludos!

Answer (score 7):

Debes usar [**strcmp()**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) para comparar cadenas en C.

```
char pal1[10],pal2[10];

printf("Ingrese una palabra: "); scanf("%s",pal1);
printf("Ingrese otra palabra: "); scanf("%s",pal2);

//if (pal1==pal2){ * INCORRECTO!
if (strcmp(pal1,pal2) == 0) {
    printf("\nTienen el mismo contenido!! \n%s\n%s",pal1,pal2);
}else{
    printf("\nSon cadenas de distinto contenido!! \n%s\n%s",pal1,pal2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para comparar dos cadenas tienes que recorrer ambas caracter por caracter. Además, el signo "==" significa identidad, no igualdad. Cuando es un tipo basico lo que hay a un lado de la sentencia sí tiene el significado de igualdad, con objetos y arrays no funciona así. Es decir `pal1==pal1` es true, `pal1==pal2`, es false, pues aunque tengan el mismo contenido son variables diferentes. La solución a tu problema sería:

```
char pal1[10],pal2[10];
  int igualdad=0;

  printf("Ingrese una palabra: "); scanf("%s",pal1);
  printf("Ingrese otra palabra: "); scanf("%s",pal2);

 for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
      if(pal1[i]!=pal2[i])
        igualdad=-1;
}
if(igualdad==0)
  printf("Las palabras son identicas");
else
printf("Las palabras son distintas");
```

Y todo esto último podrías convertirlo en un procedimiento al que le pasases ambas palabras de la siguiente forma:

```
public void compararPalabras(int longitud, char pal1[],char pal2[]){

 for (int i=0; i<longitud ; i++) 
{
      if(pal1[i]!=pal2[i])
        igualdad=-1;}
if(igualdad==0)
  printf("Las palabras son identicas");
 else
  printf("Las palabras son distintas");
}
```

La forma de llamar a este metodo en tu programa seria:

```
char pal1[10],pal2[10];

printf("Ingrese una palabra: "); scanf("%s",pal1);
printf("Ingrese otra palabra: "); scanf("%s",pal2);

compararPalabras(10,pal1,pal2);
```

Comment: no consigo que se vea bien la respuesta el for del precedimiento es for(inti=0;i<longitud;i++) {  if(pal1[i]!=pal2[i]) igualdad=-1; } if(igualdad==0) printf("Las palabras son identicas"); else printf("Las palabras son distintas");   }

Comment: Eso de que `==` significa *identidiad* y solo vale si una es constante ... ¿ de donde lo has sacado ? Me suena a programación funcional. La última vez que lo comprobé, servia perfectamente para comparar 2 variables :-)