# Error al ingresar cadena de caracteres en la salida del programa en C++

Tags: c++, string, condiciones, dev-c++, entrada

Al momento de ingresar cualquier dia de la semana de lunes a viernes de forma correcta, el codigo automaticamente ejecuta solamente el "else" de la condicional, por ejemplo, ingreso "lunes" lo cual en la salida del programa deberia de decirme "odio mi vida" pero con ninguno de los dias me funciona, alguien podria ayudarme, se los agradezco!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char dia[11];
    
    cout<<"Escriba un dia de la semana entre Lunes-Viernes, *en minusculas*"<<endl;
    
    cout<<"\nMenciona el dia: "; cin>>dia;
    
    if(dia == "lunes"){
        cout<<"Odio mi vida";
    }
    else if(dia == "martes"){
        cout<<"Que dia tan feo";
    }
    else if(dia == "miercoles"){
        cout<<"Que alegria, ya estamos a mitad de semana";
    }
    else if(dia == "jueves"){
        cout<<"Ya es jueves casi viernes";
    }
    else if(dia == "viernes"){
        cout<<"Vamonos de party";
    }
    else{
        cout<<"El dia de la semana es incorrecto";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Comparar contenido de dos cadenas en c?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106173/comparar-contenido-de-dos-cadenas-en-c)

Comment: @Trauma. Esta pregunta es en C++.

Comment: @CandidMoe Está usando `char dia[11]`, al estilo C.

Comment: @Trauma. Eso mismo. Sería provechoso que le educaras al respecto.

Answer (score 0):

Una vez inicializado un arreglo no puedes asignarle otro arreglo.

Tampoco puedes comparar el valor *global* del arreglo con el de otro.

Los literales de string son del tipo `const char*`. Sí, son punteros. Así que `==` solo devuelve `true` si ambas posiciones de memoria son iguales.

---

En C++ tienes a disposición una mejor manera, mediante la clase [`string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). Tiene muchas funciones útiles y cuenta con la sobrecarga del operador [`==`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp).

Ya estás *incluyendo* la librería [string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string). Así que solo tienes que cambiar la declaración de tu variable por:

```
string dia;
```

Con ese pequeño cambio será lo suficiente para que el resto funcione.

Answer (score 0):

Para comparar cadenas de caracteres de estilo C puedes usar la funcion `std::equal` de la biblioteca `<algorithm>` de la siguiente forma:

```
bool sw = equal(dia,dia+strlen(dia),"lunes");
```

Donde `std::strlen` de la biblioteca `<cstring>` retorna la longitud de la cadena dia, a continuacion una descripcion de los argumentos de equal:

```
equal(
    dia              , // A--> inicio de la cadena dia
    dia + strlen(dia), // B--> final de la cadena dia
    "lunes"            // C--> cadena de comparacion
);
```

- Argumento A) La variable dia es en si el inicio de la cadena.
- Argumento B) El final se calcula de la suma del inicio mas su longitud.
- Argumento C) Valor/cadena con el que sera comparada la cadena dia.

equal va a retornar true si ambas cadenas son iguales y false si son distintas.