# Terminar programa con condiciones

Tags: c, condiciones

> Realizar un programa que pregunte al usuario el momento del día con una letra (mmañana, t-tarde, n-noche), el sexo con otra letra (m-masculino, f-femenino). El programa dirá: buenos días, tardes, o noches (según el momento) señor o señora según el sexo.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    /* Realizar un programa que pregunte al usuario el momento del día con una letra 
    (mmañana, t-tarde, n-noche), el sexo con otra letra (m-masculino, f-femenino). El 
    programa dirá: buenos días, tardes, o noches (según el momento) señor o señora
    según el sexo. */

    int momento1,momento,sexo;
    printf("¿Cual es el momento del dia? (responda con ma si es mañana,t si es tarde o n si 
    es noche:>>");
    scanf("%i",&momento);
    printf("¿Cual es su sexo(responda con m si es masculino o f si es femenino");
    scanf("%i",&sexo);
  
    if(momento=="ma")
    {
       printf("Buenos dias");
    }
    else if(momento=="t")
    {
       printf("Buenas tardes");
    }
    else if(momento1=="n")
    {
       printf("Buenas noches");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Se te olvidó indicar cuál es la pregunta. ¿Qué problema tiene ese código? Ve a [edit] y lo indicas con detalle

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola Emma, puede que esté equivocado (no programo en C) pero creo que deberías poner: ***scanf("%s",&momento);***, ya que pides una letra, no un número, por otro lado, a la hora de imprimir el mensaje, tenes dos partes, por un lado la referente a la hora, y por otro la referente al sexo, y las tenés que imprimir juntas, creo que el mejor camino es crear dos variables a las que, dependiendo de la entrada del usuario, instancias con "buenos días", etc una, y la otra  con "señor" o "señora", a la hora de imprimir, las llamas desde **printf**

Comment: Reemplaza la variable `momento1` por `momento` y usa `strcmp` para comparar cadenas. En ese aspecto es duplicado.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Comparar contenido de dos cadenas en c?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106173/comparar-contenido-de-dos-cadenas-en-c)

Answer (score 1):

Todo tu código está mal.

1. Según el enunciado que expones, tienes que leer dos textos (`"ma"`, `"t"` o `"n"`  en una variable y `"m"` o `"f"` en otra), pero en lugar de leer texto, lees números:

   ```
   int momento1,momento,sexo;
   // …
   scanf("%i",&momento); // momento es un número (int)
   // …
   scanf("%i",&sexo);    // sexo es un número (int)
   ```

   Si pides leer un número e introduces un texto, la función `scanf` no leerá nada, puedes comprobar si se realizó una lectura verificando el valor de retorno, si coincide con la cantidad de datos leídos es que funcionó; en tu caso no funciona.
2. Estás comparando números (`int`) con literales de texto (como `"ma"`). Los literales de texto en [c](/questions/tagged/c) son una formación<sup>1</sup> de caracteres, las formaciones se convierten implícitamente a punteros al primer elemento y los punteros son comparables con un número; por eso la comparación no da un error (puede que de una alarma) pero probablemente nunca sea cierta:

   ```
   //        vv <--- Esto compara un número con un puntero.
   if(momento=="ma")
   {
       printf("Buenos dias");
   }
   //             vv <--- Esto compara un número con un puntero.
   else if(momento=="t")
   {
       printf("Buenas tardes");
   }
   //              vv <--- Esto compara un número con un puntero.
   else if(momento1=="n")
   {
       printf("Buenas noches");
   }
   ```
3. Si quieres leer cadenas, debes usar `scanf` con `%s` sobre una formación<sup>1</sup> de caracteres.

   ```
   char momento[3];
   char sexo[2];

   printf("¿Cual es el momento del dia? (responda con ma si es mañana,t si es tarde o n si es noche:\n");
   scanf("%s", momento);

   printf("¿Cual es su sexo(responda con m si es masculino o f si es femenino\n");
   scanf("%s", sexo);
   ```
4. Si quieres comparar cadenas, debes usar la función `strcmp` (`str`ing `c`o`mp`are), que devuelve `0` si ambas cadenas eran iguales; ten en cuenta que no distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas.

   ```
    if (strcmp(momento, "ma") == 0)
        momento_id = 0;
    else if (strcmp(momento, "t") == 0)
        momento_id = 1;
    else if (strcmp(momento, "n") == 0)
        momento_id = 2;

    if (strcmp(sexo, "m") == 0)
        sexo_id = 0;
    else if (strcmp(sexo, "f") == 0)
        sexo_id = 1;
   ```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZFfSsNAEMafu6cYIoVEqrT1zVoFPUYMsmw27UIyWzIbEEoP1RMI9mBxNt22UVLfdv588/12Rt2tlGrbG4OqbHINT@RyY@/Xz6Kfqg2ufE4YdFBJg3EitmKk1rKG28pWGp2lNIMlbCNLkBtJ0QQilARO1rk@R2jVmqPd4iQm/XlW@ibpa6EYBqcP2andd6fzzHdsmMkVcfT99dbIEjSBLk8KyPnNEC8Q15o2FnMJyiKTAxnfWsnDXqKcuBB3kGABQ9xhPr5jlLAzKYlsNPafCAbJMAE1HeEf07MnqaY0aNmnCLlC8zhODTj5QZ1Nt/Kj7YfJjwV@dKUCYj6OqjZx6OANVjJKYLmEaSJGo4uQNzxlC12ShkGduyab/SvDa7L5QgD8YvTkHrCnCJ@5AhcExaBg1r/Ba6NxzAfQh72t@5ei9AKVHZdHaRiSdfuttWtq9P67tq2kKMQP)</kbd>.

---

###### <sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.