# Mi switch/case me lleva directamente a default y no se porque/ lenguaje C

Tags: c

Mi profesora de informatica nos dejo un problema para lenguaje C, en esta tengo que hacer un codigo mediante 3 tipos de respuestas posibles para dar un resultado impreso, pero tengo problemas que ni siquiera mi propia profesora me supo como responder

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    /*
    Haga un programa para calcular lo que hay que pagar por un conjunto de llamadas 
    telefónicas.
    Por cada llamada se ingresa el tipo (Internacional, Nacional, Local) y la duración en 
    minutos.  
    El criterio que se sigue para calcular el costo de cada llamada es el siguiente:
    Internacional: 3 primeros minutos $7.59 Cada minuto adicional $3.03
    Nacional: 3 primeros minutos $1.20 Cada minuto adicional $0.48
    */
    int main()
    {
        int tiempo,precio;
        char tllamada[20];
        tiempo=0;
        precio=0;
    
        printf("Que tipo de llamada quiere hacer?\n");
        scanf("%s",tllamada);
       if(tllamada[14]="internacional"){
            tllamada[14]="interna";
        }
        printf("Cuantos minutos va a usar?\n");
        scanf("%i",&tiempo);
        switch ("%s",tllamada[14]){
            case 'interna':
            if (tiempo<=3){
                precio=tiempo*7.59;
                printf("\nEl precio de la llamada sera: $%i",precio,"pesos");
            } else {
                tiempo=tiempo-3;
                precio=(3*7.59)+(tiempo*3.03);
                printf("\nEl precio de la llamada sera: $%i",precio,"pesos");
            }
            break;
            case 'nacional':
            if (tiempo<=3){
                precio=tiempo*1.2;
                printf("\nEl precio de la llamada sera: $%i",precio,"pesos");
            } else {
                tiempo=tiempo-3;
                precio=(3*1.2)+(tiempo*0.48);
                printf("\nEl precio de la llamada sera: $%i",precio,"pesos");
            }
            break;
            case 'local':
                printf("No tienes que pagar nada,\n disfruta tu llamada :)");
            break;
            default:
                printf("No se acepta esta opcion");
            break;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Comparar contenido de dos cadenas en c?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106173/comparar-contenido-de-dos-cadenas-en-c)

Answer (score 1):

En el código presentado, hay algunos errores en el uso del lenguaje que deben ser destacados.

En esta parte del código, se asigna la dirección de memoria de la cadena "*internacional*" a la posición `llamada[14]`.
Esta condición provoca que el valor de la variable llamada sea alterado a la dirección de memoria de la cadena "*internaciona*".

```
char tllamada[20];
     
printf("Que tipo de llamada quiere hacer?\n");
scanf("%s",tllamada);
if(tllamada[14]="internacional"){
     tllamada[14]="interna";
   }
```

En este caso, lo que debería hacerse es comparar el contenido de la cadena, el uso de la función [strcmp()](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcmp-wcscmp-mbscmp?view=msvc-170) resuelve esta parte:

```
printf("Que tipo de llamada quiere hacer?\n");
scanf("%s", tllamada);

if (strcmp(tllamada, "internacional") == 0) {
   strcpy(tllamada, "interna");
 }
```

De esta manera está comprando strings, esta función `strcmp` proviene de la biblioteca **string.h**.

**En esta parte que programó**: El switch compara un único valor, ya sea un número entero o solo un carácter, y la respuesta se basa en lo que se programó, se está comparando más de 1 carácter.
El estándar de **C** en el caso del `switch` no compara secuencias de caracteres.

```
 printf("Cuantos minutos va a usar?\n");
 scanf("%i",&tiempo);
        
 switch ("%s",tllamada[14]){
         
   case 'interna':
       if (tiempo<=3){
          precio=tiempo*7.59;
          printf("\nEl precio de la llamada sera: $%i",precio,"pesos");
          ..... Continuación del código.
```

La forma en que el **[switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/c-language/switch-statement-c?view=msvc-170)** debería estar, el switch va a comparar el primer carácter `tllamada[0]`

```
switch (tllamada[0]) {
        case 'i':   
            if (tiempo <= 3) {
                precio = tiempo * 7.59;
            } else {
                tiempo = tiempo - 3;
                precio = (3 * 7.59) + (tiempo * 3.03);
            }
            ..... Continuación del código.
```

El código completo corregido, la elección siempre caerá en el primer `case`, debido a la condición creada anteriormente `if (strcmp(tllamada, "internacional") == 0):`

Lo que podría hacer que el algoritmo sea más lógico es presentar un mensaje para las opciones

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  int tiempo, precio;
  char tllamada[20];


printf("Ingresa 'i' - para interna\n");
printf("Ingresa 'n' - para nacional\n");
printf("Ingresa 'l' - para local\n");

scanf(" %c", &tllamada[0]);


  printf("Cuantos minutos va a usar?\n");
  scanf("%i", &tiempo);

  switch (tllamada[0]) {
  case 'i':
    if (tiempo <= 3) {
      precio = tiempo * 7.59;
    } else {
      tiempo = tiempo - 3;
      precio = (3 * 7.59) + (tiempo * 3.03);
    }
    printf("\nEl precio de la llamada sera: $%i pesos\n", precio);

    break;
  case 'n':
    if (tiempo <= 3) {
      precio = tiempo * 1.2;
    } else {
      tiempo = tiempo - 3;
      precio = (3 * 1.2) + (tiempo * 0.48);
    }
    printf("\nEl precio de la llamada sera: $%i pesos\n", precio);
    break;
  case 'l':
    printf("No tienes que pagar nada,\n disfruta tu llamada :)\n");
    break;
  default:
    printf("No se acepta esta opcion\n");
    break;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Pero manteniendo el algoritmo inicial con las debidas correcciones.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  int tiempo, precio;
  char tllamada[20];

  printf("Que tipo de llamada quiere hacer?\n");
  scanf("%s", tllamada);

  if (strcmp(tllamada, "internacional") == 0) {
    strcpy(tllamada, "interna");
  }

  printf("Cuantos minutos va a usar?\n");
  scanf("%i", &tiempo);

  switch (tllamada[0]) {
  case 'i':
    if (tiempo <= 3) {
      precio = tiempo * 7.59;
    } else {
      tiempo = tiempo - 3;
      precio = (3 * 7.59) + (tiempo * 3.03);
    }
    printf("\nEl precio de la llamada sera: $%i pesos\n", precio);

    break;
  case 'n':
    if (tiempo <= 3) {
      precio = tiempo * 1.2;
    } else {
      tiempo = tiempo - 3;
      precio = (3 * 1.2) + (tiempo * 0.48);
    }
    printf("\nEl precio de la llamada sera: $%i pesos\n", precio);
    break;
  case 'l':
    printf("No tienes que pagar nada,\n disfruta tu llamada :)\n");
    break;
  default:
    printf("No se acepta esta opcion\n");
    break;
  }

  return 0;
}
```